# WCF not exposing fields but uses ExtensionData

Tags: wcf, datacontract

Im trying to create a WCF which consumes a List

```
  public class myClass { 
       public int ID { get;set;}
  }
```

In my service i write

```
    [DataContract]
    public class myClass
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
    }
```

And my client nows the entity

```
   ServiceReference2.myClass[] sendData = new ServiceReference2.myClass[2];
```

but when i would add a new myClass to the array like

```
   ServiceReference2.myClass add1= new ServiceReference2.myClass();
```

the entity only exposes the field 'ExtensionData' and not the field ID

What am i doing wrong

Answer (score 7):

You forgot to decorate the ID property with the DataMember attribute:

```
[DataContract]
public class myClass
{
    [DataMember]
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```